# Facebook send a message

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm using Facebook `PHP-SDK` and the `JS-SDK` and trying to display a dialog whenever the user logs in for the first time that will list all his friends and will allow him to select the ones he wants to invite to my website.

I already figured out how to display the friend list.
I want the invitation to be sent via facebook message (pre-composed message that the user can edit) and not as a application invitation.

I looked through the Facebook documentation and I can't find this feature anywhere.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook does not allow applications to send messages, only notifications.

Comment: I want the actual user to send the message, I just want to display the user list, let him choose and then he will press the 'send' button. still not possible?

Comment: Still not possible, as there's no way for Facebook to know if the user actually did it themselves.

Comment: Can you share some pointers to the documentation to 'send notifications'?

Answer (score 2):

You can link the invite button to something like this..
"http://www.facebook.com/inbox/?compose&id=#{facebook identifier of the friend}&message= Hey!+Check+out+this+cool+website"
and open this in a new tab.

Comment: It seems Facebook changed the format: http://www.facebook.com/messages/[user id]?msg_prefill=message

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow you to send messages . Either way , you can post to the user's friends feed on behalf of the user , with a custom message and the the notification for the post in feed will be displayed.